# Cannot run conda command 'activate' with NppExec plugin of Notepad++

Tags: python, windows, notepad++, conda, nppexec

If I run

```
activate my_environment
```

from a command prompt `conda` correctly switches to the desired environment, but if I execute the following temporary script from NppExec plugin

```
activate my_environment
python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

I get the error message

```
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
```

where last line means "file not found". If I omit the `activate` line the script runs as expected.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

I got anaconda environment working from within nppExec using,

```
cd <AnacondaPath>\Anaconda3\condabin
activate.bat <env name> & python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```