# Python script not terminating properly in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++, anaconda3, nppexec

I have installed anaconda3 and notepad++, I'm trying to link NppExec, a Notepad++'s plugin so that not only I can run both pure python and other libraries (like matplotlib or numpy). I have found one solution at: [Cannot run conda command 'activate' with NppExec plugin of Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338677/cannot-run-conda-command-activate-with-nppexec-plugin-of-notepad)

This solution works, however when I run it the execution of the process does not terminate and I am forced to press Ctrl+C in the console to terminate it manually. I think this is due to anaconda's activate file not having an end (probably in the bat file?). Is there a workaround to this? Maybe with a termination clause in the bat file or a clever workaround in notepad?

Comment: If you're using `activate.bat <env name> & python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` as in the linked SO post, then the `-i` is what's preventing the termination. Just remove the `-i`.

Comment: Yess, thank you! I definitely did not understand that from the documentation: inspect interactively after running script: forces prompt even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Justin commented use activate.bat  & python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" and it closes automatically after the execution